# Update a Chrome extension via inline install?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using chrome.webstore.install to install my extension (see
https://github.com/eloquence/freeyourstuff.cc/blob/c7c581b63ad179cd6d0ddc4576f302defa7b17fa/service/frontend/install.js#L30), which works fine. But when triggering this in an update context where the user has an older version installed, it just seems to pretend that it's installing the new version, but the end result is that the user is still using the old version.

Is there a way to actually update via JavaScript, or do I have to rely entirely on the webstore's auto-update mechanism for that?

Comment: [chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck) inside the extension.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I'll give that a try.